# outputting the results in tik tak toe

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am creating a program which has a constant value for the possible wins in a game of tik tak toe. inside of the function it should determine whether or not a winning play has been made and output to the console whether X has won and O has lost or vice versa.

For example
console.log(diagonalWinInverse);
should output
X Won
O Lost

I am just starting out and i am a little lost on how to begin.

```
const rowWin = [
  ["O", "O", "O"],
  ["", "", ""],
  ["", "", ""]
]

const colWin = [
  ["", "X", ""],
  ["", "X", ""],
  ["", "X", ""]
]

const diagonalWin = [
  ["", "", "O"],
  ["", "O", ""],
  ["O", "", ""]
]

const diagonalWinInverse = [
  ["X", "", ""],
  ["", "X", ""],
  ["", "", "X"]
]
//This function will evaluate all the grids I have defined above
//And will tell the user which sign has won

let ask = prompt("Please Choose an option and only select the number:\n 1 Row Win \n2 Column Win \n3 Diagonal Win \n4 Inverse Diagonal Win")

function evaluatePlay(grid){



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and use for loops to compare two grids. If a cell is empty in either of the grids, then skip check. If three cells are equal, that means there is a match (someone won).

```js
const rowWin = [
  ["O", "O", "O"],
  ["", "", ""],
  ["", "", ""]
]

const colWin = [
  ["", "X", ""],
  ["", "X", ""],
  ["", "X", ""]
]

const diagonalWin = [
  ["", "", "O"],
  ["", "O", ""],
  ["O", "", ""]
]

const diagonalWinInverse = [
  ["X", "", ""],
  ["", "X", ""],
  ["", "", "X"]
]

function compare2grids(grid1, grid2)
{
  let count = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      if (grid1[i][j] === "" || grid2[i][j] === "") {
        continue;
      }
      else if (grid1[i][j] == grid2[i][j]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  return count === 3;
}

function evaluatePlay(grid){
  console.log(compare2grids(grid, diagonalWinInverse));
  console.log(compare2grids(grid, diagonalWin));
}

evaluatePlay([
  ["X", "O", "O"],
  ["", "X", ""],
  ["O", "O", "X"]
]);
```